# Offset animated color change over many objects?

Tags: animation, materials, objects

So I'm making an animation where I want about a dozen or so objects which all look the same to change their color, but with each object doing it at a different point, making a kind of swipe color change effect. But I don't want to make a bunch of different materials and animate each individual one. Help Please?

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could probably use some kind of animated texture, or this addon http://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/425-arewo-the-animation-replicator-with-offset.html

Comment: ok so I'm watching that tutorial, and I ran this script that is run at 19:54 and this is the code I have so far:    import bpy
import math

loops = 10

distanceX = 0.1
distanceY = 0
distanceZ = 0

rotationX = 0
rotationY = 0
rotationZ = 0

offset = 3
for i in range(loops):
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate = {"linked":False})
    obj.location[0] += distanceX
    obj.location[1] += distanceY
    obj.location[2] += distanceZ
    obj.rotation_euler[0] += rotationX
    obj.rotation_euler[1] += rotationY
    obj.rotation_euler[2] += rotationZ

Comment: Sorry, ran out of characters. So I put that code in, but  I get this error: line 17, in <module>
NameError: name 'obj' is not defined.
That line is this one:
    obj.location[0] += distanceX

HELP!

Comment: consider 
`obj = bpy.context.active_object`
 on the line before the error.... this defines the name obj .... perhaps you missed copying a line.  This is only to address your syntax error.

Comment: oh ok. yah, it didn't have that line. now it works just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(01) (Difficult the first time) A color texture influence driver can be used ... with a numeric [custom property] .. 24, 48, 72 and so on ... on the objects ... object data.  This would not be a lengthy script.
You must locate the target of the script in the outliner datablocks view with great care as depicted below.  This requires effort because it is deep hierarchy .  Most people I  suspect have rarely used the datablocks view. The Blender UI debug info  will not behave as desired. Object location x, y, z scripts have better debug info.  If you attempt to write a texture driver from the properties window it will fail.  Blender will not give warning.  Note the driver is located on the Cube object not its material.  Below I typed a distinctive numeric value of .678, not 0 or 1,into the field to help me locate it in the datablock view.  Note the absence of the driver in the texture panel.

The final render will be correct.
Code

frame > 20

[image]

(02) Special case .. if the objects are static and identical with simple color... you may be able to join them and UV Map them together. Use a single texture that is an [image  sequence] to slide the color across them.  Your image sequence may need to be structured as twelve logical strips or color.

(03) Materials and textures are not the same .. I would consider 12 textures ... perhaps copying colors ... and keyframe the color influence of the texture. I am assuming you will not have more than 12.  (I am supposed to avoid asking for clarification according to the yellow box text).  This would avoid a lengthy script.

(04) The more objects you have the more utility of the driver or script.

Comment: Ok so I tried your animated texture method, and it worked just fine. thanks! I also want to try your first one, the pseudo code? where would I type that in?

Comment: RMB Right Mouse Button the property and select one of the following options.
Add Drivers. ...   Blender Link    http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Drivers ..  See a video site for newer Blender driver video. ... I suggest you first modify only something simple like the x position of object. (frame * .02) code.  The material drivers are not working as expected at this time today.  I may post a question here at this site.  A new topic might be better.

Comment: I am still investigating material driver updates.  There are differences from simple position of an object.  So (01) of the answer will be updated when I have a clear statement.

Comment: @DragonHeart So above is the driver for a material texture color influence.  That is not necessarily a recommendation to use it.

Comment: Oh wow! thank you so much for your advice! It helps a TON! Thanks!