# Particles, how to trigger object's animation on birth?

Tags: animation, objects, particles

I have a particle system, I'm using an animated object as a particle, the particle system's period is 40 frames, which is the same as the lifetime, since I need every particle to play the animation once, then disappear. How can I make the animation of each particle start when it's born?
The case right now is that the animation starts when the first particle is born, so the first particle is fine, but for instance, the particle born on frame 35, is animated for the last 5 frames only of the animation! 
I know it's better to upload the blend file, but I can't for this project, and screen shots won't really add any more explanation, it's a generic question for a basic operation, that I've been trying to do for 3 days! Appreciate all help.

Comment: You could take a look at [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18047/make-animated-particle-object-start-animation-from-the-beginning-when-emitted) question

Comment: I came through this question before posting mine, this simply wont work, it might in some cases though.

Comment: What's the animation like of each particle intended to be like? Changes in the material? Scale of the particle?

Comment: @Poyo as I mentioned in the question, the particles are animated objects. The particle system is controlling the location and rotation of particles, the object is a simple mesh parented to an armature, the armature is animating the object.

Comment: But all objects are dupli... so how to have an animation for each ? ... well, this is your question : )

Comment: @lemon For instance in 3DS Max, you can treat instances in absolute or relative, so relative will treat each object when created as frame (1) in it's animation, so it's animation starts when it's born.
I need to know if there's such thing in Blender's Particle System, because I couldn't find nowhere, if there isn't, there must be a workaround, I'm sure I'm not the first person to go through this issue :)